# Devise - uninitialized constant User::PasswordHistory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise

I have a rails 3 application that I am working on and have implemented devise. I have it working, and now I wish to extend it so that a user is unable to use a old password more than once. Found this functionality on github which to my suprise was good. [Disallow previously passwords - Git Hub](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Disallow-previously-used-passwords)

I thought this would straight forward but it is clearly not. My code looks like the following:

**create_passwrod_histories.rb**

```
class CreatePasswordHistories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:password_histories) do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string  :encrypted_password
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :password_histories
  end
end
```

*User.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  has_many :roles_users
  has_many :roles, :through => :roles_users
  has_many :projects
  has_many :password_histories
  after_save :store_digest


  # authorization include this in whichever model that will use ACL9
  acts_as_authorization_subject
   def has_role?(role_name, object=nil)
    !! if object.nil?
      self.roles.find_by_name(role_name.to_s) ||
      self.roles.member?(get_role(role_name, nil))
    else
      method = "is_#{role_name.to_s}?".to_sym
      object.respond_to?(method) && object.send(method, self)
    end
  end



  def login(user)
    post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[username]' => user.username, 'user[password]' => user.password
  end
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable #:registerable,
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable
  acts_as_authorization_subject  :association_name => :roles
  attr_accessor :login
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :id, :login, :username, :full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_ids

   email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates_presence_of :username, :full_name
  validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[-\w\._@]+$/i, :allow_blank => true, :message => "should only contain letters, numbers, or . - _ @"
  validates_length_of :username, :minimum => 1, :allow_blank => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format   => { :with => email_regex }
  validates :password, :unique_password => true

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
   conditions = warden_conditions.dup
   login = conditions.delete(:login)
   where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  end

  private

  def store_digest
    if encrypted_password_changed?
      PasswordHistory.create(:user => self, :encrypted_password => encrypted_password)
    end
  end


end
```

**unique_password_validator.rb**

```
require 'bcrypt'
class UniquePasswordValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.password_histories.each do |ph|
      bcrypt = ::BCrypt::Password.new(ph.encrypted_password)
      hashed_value = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret([value, Devise.pepper].join, bcrypt.salt)
      record.errors[attribute] << "has been used previously." and return if hashed_value == ph.encrypted_password
    end
  end
end
```

I then run my app and try to use the same password. It then throws up the follwoing error `uninitialized constant User::PasswordHistory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I can see from your code why that would be happening is if you didn't have the `PasswordHistory` model object. That code from Github doesn't actually explicitly tell you to do it, but you certainly need it. So, maybe you created and ran the migration but forgot to create the model, as in:

```
class PasswordHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```

Comment: Okay so I got rid of the errors and tried this and it didn't work thanks replying